# The best practice to migrate to an SSD and add Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, ssd, data-migration

First some details. 
I am running Windows 7 on a laptop. I've cut my C: drive down to ~100gb, and have a 250g SSD which I will replace my internal HDD. I would also like to install Ubuntu on the SSD. I have a SATA/USB cord to migrate Windows onto the SSD.

While the drive is empty, should I create some partitions? Should they all be NTFS, or are there better practices for dual booting Windows 7/Ubuntu?

I am also concerned about the SSD booting up fine with my Windows clone once booted. Are there ways to prepare for this issue?

Any other tips to make this transition smooth would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Running Linux in double boort with Windows is always a difficult suggestion because of the complications with the Grub and the incompatible file systems. But if you are a Linux expert, you may be able to manage. I prefer to run my **[Linux distros in VMware Player](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=475A0A48CA6D4035&id=475A0A48CA6D4035%211853)**.
2. If you put Ubuntu on the SSD, use Ubuntu 14.04 because that is the first release that supports Trim per default. Without Trim you would degrade the performance of your SSD.
3. For migrating your Windows to the SSD, you have a couple of options:

a) you can do it 'manually' with an image. But there you have to make sure you align the SSD first and shut off defrag. I have written **[a tutorial that explains](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/149969-ssd-install-transfer-operating-system.html)** the steps.

b) You can spend $19.95 for the **[Paragon Migration Tool](http://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/components/migrate-OS-to-SSD/)**. That does everything for you automatically in 3 clicks. That is an excellent program and has never failed around here.

Comment: Turns out migrating was easy. However, installing Ubuntu is giving me a lot of problems due to how need versions of Windows boot. Trying to resolve that not. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah right. Mixing Windows and Linux is problematic. That's why I always choose the virtual route for Linux. The other way around works just as well.